# Need to add diagonal view in recycler horizontal mode

Tags: android

[image]I need to create recyclerview view with diagonal tilted layout.I have already tried rotation property but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tool="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="categoryListData"
            type="tv.jadoo.model.home.response.HomeItemBean" />
    </data>


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">




            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:imageUrl="@{categoryListData.backdropImage}"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/image_container"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/view_category_selected"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg_selector" />


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@color/focus_color"
                    android:id="@+id/image_home_un_selected"
                    app:imageUrl="@{categoryListData.itemImage}"
                    android:layout_height="40dp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:id="@+id/image_home_selected"
                    android:src="@color/focus_color"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    app:imageUrl="@{categoryListData.selectedImage}"
                    android:layout_height="40dp" />

                <tv.jadoo.customui.CustomTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@{categoryListData.name}"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:id="@+id/tv_home_banner_category_title"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    custom:fontName="@string/font_extra_bold"
                    tool:text="Name"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout
</layout>
```

Its my layout file and frame layout work as parent view and I also add data binding.

Comment: "it doesn't work" is a very broad notion. What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Do you get a different result than the desired? And where is your code?

Comment: Rotation rotate whole layout but I need to rotate only top angle.

Comment: have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207559/overlap-positions-views-in-recyclerview

Comment: @Ashish Mishra have you solved your problem.. i have a same problem with vertical list. see this link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44839623/how-to-make-dynamic-diagonal-view-list