# Remove space gap between recycler view rows

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Okay, i looked around and found nothing about this particular case.

I have a vertical recyclerView, in a Linear Layout (so android:height is set to 0dp, in order to support weight function). This recyclerView contains a virtually infinite list of days. When the user scroll, the current day (or row if you want) change its background to transparent, in order to show that it is the current day. I notice only later that the item row doesn't fit the all space the recyclerView give to that row. 
If you see the image, everything will be clearer: i highlight one little and tiny row, different of color (is not white). This is the recyclerView background!
So, my question is, why the item layout doesn't fit all the row space?

[image]

Also: this is the recyclerView xml:

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6.0"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_recycler_view_main"/>
```

And this is the row:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/row_day"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="180dp"
android:background="@color/white">

<View
    android:id="@+id/vertical_row"
    android:layout_width="3dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/budget_remains"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/day_number0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vertical_row"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/vertical_row"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:text="@string/day_number_fake"
    android:textColor="@color/day_number_and_name"
    android:textSize="@dimen/day_number" />

<TextView
    style="@style/DayInfoMain"
    android:id="@+id/day_name0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/day_number0"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/day_number0"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/day_number0"
    android:text="@string/day_name_fake" />

<TextView
    style="@style/AmountDayAndExpense"
    android:id="@+id/day_amount0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/day_name0"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/day_amount_fake"
    android:textSize="@dimen/day_text" />
```

and as requested, the background_recycler_view_main:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient android:type="radial"
    android:startColor="@color/white"
    android:endColor="@color/background_main_component"
    android:gradientRadius="200dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Show the `background_recycler_view_main` code .

Comment: There it is, but sincerly, i don't understand why should this be important...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like divider lines between different items.
Try this in the class where you have made the instance of the Recyclerview
I assume if the instance is like this

```
Recyclerview mRecyclerView = (Recyclerview) findviewbyId(R.id.recycler_view);
```

Then add this line below to make the divider empty

```
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            // Do not draw the divider
        }
    });
```

Comment: I never used a DividerItemDecoration, so there is no divider at all.
Also, i tried your code, but no effect.

Comment: Does this answer helps adding negetive margin to recyclerview 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35207851/4204668

Answer (score 0):

Elevation is causing the `shadow effect` for the `recycler items`.Remove this line of code from the recycler view

```
android:elevation="5dp"
```

Comment: Nope. Removing elevation has no effect.