# Android timeline view layout issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making one time line view in my application. In layout i am getting too much space between two dots.

I have taken a `Recyclerview`. I am using this layout as its item. Below is my current output and code.

**My Output :**

[image]

**Expected Output :**  (Ignore this colors. i just want view like this)

[image]

**My code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <data>

            <import type="android.view.View" />

            <variable
                name="obj"
                type="com.smartcompliant.model.ComplaintProgressModel" />
        </data>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:background="@drawable/complaint_status"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorGreen" />


                    <View
                        android:layout_width="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryCompHistory"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:visibility="@{obj.isLast ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
                </LinearLayout>



                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/line_box"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorTextHint"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_left" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_10"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@{obj.title1}"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_14"
                            android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                            android:text="@{obj.title2}"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/font_12"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextHint" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

Let me know if you require any other code. Please suggest something. Thank you !

Comment: Please checked this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207559/overlap-positions-views-in-recyclerview/35207851#35207851

Comment: @MetehanToksoy It is working.. but it gives decor to first item as well so it will be cut. any suggestion for this?

Comment: this will be too manual but you can add padding to the recyclerview.

Comment: @MetehanToksoy Yeah Thank you so much! it solved my issue. Please post an answer for future visitors, I will mark it

Comment: You're welcome. I posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative margin as suggested @Evin1_'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207559/overlap-positions-views-in-recyclerview/35207851#35207851).

And for the first item visibility problem, this might be too manual but you can give padding-top to the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 3):

Here, I didn't make RecycleView for it, I just copy paste the code for the multiple rows.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/ll_dots"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/drawable_btn_green"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


            <View
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:visibility="@{obj.isLast ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll_dots"
            android:id="@+id/ll_one"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/grey_round_rect"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/Green"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@{obj.title1}"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@{obj.title2}"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your code is perfect but not matching my requirement. actually i want the textview layout pointing on dot not in middle of dots..Any suggestion please

Comment: take margin from the `TextView` to `View`

Comment: Yes i am telling that i want whole view image and text on right side of dot not on right of view.. it should be starting from dot.do you get what i am trying to explain?